# Problem with dual screen setup - external monitor works individually

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.6 and encountered some problems with my second screen.

My hardware: Lenovo legion y540, nvidia geforce 1660 ti, amd ryzen 4800H.

I've noticed strange behavior with my second monitor- depending which driver i choose from "Additional drivers" in "software and updates" it works differently, none satisfies me. Btw graphics card is not detected by ubuntu.

With all of the Nvidia drivers (470, 510, 515, 520) and second monitor plugged in i get some sort of "console" output on laptop screen and gui on second screen:[photo of console output with active gui on second display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AaTo.jpg), without second screen plugged in i only get console output.

While using "X.Org X server - Nouveau"  only laptop screen works - it works correctly with gui, but does not detect second screen.

I'v tried installing all recomended drivers with `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`
and changing `options nvidia-drm modeset=0` in `/lib/modprobe.d/nvidia-kms.conf`.

If it matters i've also change grub config from `quite splash` to `nomodeset` - had problems with booting.

I'm completly new to ubuntu so, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you still using the nomodeset command in Grub?

Comment: yes, didn't changed that.

Comment: 1. Of course `nomodeset`, a workaround matters! It precludes loading of ANY driver! 2. For GTX1660 the driver is 515, period. 3. Unless you're dual-booting with Windows 11 then you can disable Secure Boot in UEFI. That should be all: Install the correct driver version, disable Secure Boot (or manually sign the drivers with MOK util, **do NOT use nomodeset**

Comment: ChaganAuto, I'm dualbooting with Windows 10, so i assume that Secure Boot should stay enabled ?

Answer (score 0):

Generally you do not want nomodeset as permanent boot parameter. Its just needed until you install the NVIDIA proprietary driver from the Ubuntu repository That is part of your problem. You are telling the OS not to use the NVIDIA card. That is what nomodeset does, it is a temp fix just to get you installed and logged in so you can install the correct driver.

Comment: Unfortunatelly it did not helped or helped partially. To be sure i done everything correctly i reinstalled Ubuntu one again, booted once with nomodeset parameter in grub, and set nvidia 515 driver as active. 

After reboot i have external screen working, displaying desktop gui, and my laptop screen displaying black screen with line `/dev/nvme0n1p6: clean, 190425/6979584 files, 3103821/27904000 blocks` as it was when i first booted ubuntu, without any changes.

Comment: if I unplug HDMI, black screen stays.

Comment: Review the screen settings in the OS.

Comment: In display settings panel there is only one screen visible - external one.

Comment: Have you disabled Secure Boot yet?

Comment: Yes, Secure boot is disabled.

Comment: Fixed the problem by changing from "switchable graphics" to "discrete graphics" in bios settings. Idk if it is optimal solution, but at least it works.